# Memory usage in Linux R

Tags: linux, r, centos

I am loading a 6 GB dataset in R running over Centos Linux 6.3, 128 GB RAM, 16 Core machine.
Simultaneously I am monitoring the RAM usage with top command. After about 104 minutes, in the  output of the top command, the VIRT column shows 189 GB.

Now, I am not able to understand how the VIRT column shows more than 128GB (which is the limit). Is there some kind of shared memory that is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is simple rule with the virtual memory.

Linux is using RAM for often used processes, but other one it can store at the hard drive, as a virtual memory.

In my opinion, better way to get real memory usage is to use **free -m** command.

Comment: So you are saying, Linux will swap data between RAM and hard drive as and when requirements go up? Is there a limit to how much of hd space can be taken up by RAM?

Comment: Read about swap. But there is other way too, in ex sawpon commmad.

Comment: @Indrajit Size of swap partition. Also, http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ is useful.